# Move wanted data from json to array using

Tags: php, arrays, json

Hey I am trying to move wanted data fron json. So the data inside the json are booking data from a hotel, I got it from query to database. Basically, there are multiple data with same date on it. I just want to move data that I want to php array using simple else if statement but I can't make it works.

Here is the rule:
1. So 'booked' is more important than 'available'. Even if it is still 'available', if someone 'booked' it. For example April 10th is 'booked' the only data I want is 'April 10th booked' I don't care if it is still available. This rule also applies to 'full'. 'Booked' is more important than 'full'.

2. Last rule: 'Booked' is equvalent with 'Missed' and 'Attended'

Here is the json:

```
array(128) {
  [0]=>
  array(6) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-03 08:00"
    ["end"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-03 08:30"
    ["id_course"]=>
    string(5) "55508"
    ["image"]=>
    string(92) "http://squline.dev/dashboard/media/images/teacher/2dd22e63084c868044b8d8840ad02e35_thumb.jpg"
    ["className"]=>
    string(23) "custom-cursor bg-booked"
    ["title"]=>
    string(8) "Attended"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-03 08:00"
    ["end"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-03 08:30"
    ["id_course"]=>
    string(5) "55508"
    ["className"]=>
    string(21) "custom-cursor bg-full"
    ["title"]=>
    string(4) "Full"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(6) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-03 08:30"
    ["end"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-03 09:00"
    ["id_course"]=>
    string(5) "55520"
    ["className"]=>
    string(23) "custom-cursor bg-booked"
    ["title"]=>
    string(8) "Attended"
    ["image"]=>
    string(92) "http://squline.dev/dashboard/media/images/teacher/2dd22e63084c868044b8d8840ad02e35_thumb.jpg"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(5) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-03 08:30"
    ["end"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-03 09:00"
    ["id_course"]=>
    string(5) "55520"
    ["className"]=>
    string(21) "custom-cursor bg-full"
    ["title"]=>
    string(4) "Full"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(5) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-03 09:00"
    ["end"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-03 09:30"
    ["id_course"]=>
    string(5) "55520"
    ["className"]=>
    string(21) "custom-cursor bg-full"
    ["title"]=>
    string(4) "Full"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(5) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-03 09:30"
    ["end"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-03 10:00"
    ["id_course"]=>
    string(5) "55520"
    ["className"]=>
    string(21) "custom-cursor bg-full"
    ["title"]=>
    string(4) "Full"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(5) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-03 10:30"
    ["end"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-03 11:00"
    ["id_course"]=>
    string(5) "55520"
    ["className"]=>
    string(21) "custom-cursor bg-full"
    ["title"]=>
    string(4) "Full"
  }
  [7]=>
  array(6) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-03 17:00"
    ["end"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-03 17:30"
    ["id_course"]=>
    string(5) "55520"
    ["className"]=>
    string(21) "custom-cursor bg-past"
    ["title"]=>
    string(9) "Available"
    ["status"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [8]=>
  array(6) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-03 17:30"
    ["end"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-03 18:00"
    ["id_course"]=>
    string(5) "55520"
    ["className"]=>
    string(21) "custom-cursor bg-past"
    ["title"]=>
    string(9) "Available"
    ["status"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [9]=>
  array(6) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-03 18:00"
    ["end"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-03 18:30"
    ["id_course"]=>
    string(5) "55520"
    ["className"]=>
    string(21) "custom-cursor bg-past"
    ["title"]=>
    string(9) "Available"
    ["status"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [10]=>
  array(6) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-03 18:30"
    ["end"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-03 19:00"
    ["id_course"]=>
    string(5) "55520"
    ["className"]=>
    string(21) "custom-cursor bg-past"
    ["title"]=>
    string(9) "Available"
    ["status"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [11]=>
  array(6) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-03 19:00"
    ["end"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-03 19:30"
    ["id_course"]=>
    string(5) "55520"
    ["className"]=>
    string(21) "custom-cursor bg-past"
    ["title"]=>
    string(9) "Available"
    ["status"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [12]=>
  array(6) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-03 19:30"
    ["end"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-03 20:00"
    ["id_course"]=>
    string(5) "55520"
    ["className"]=>
    string(21) "custom-cursor bg-past"
    ["title"]=>
    string(9) "Available"
    ["status"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [13]=>
  array(6) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-03 20:00"
    ["end"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-03 20:30"
    ["id_course"]=>
    string(5) "55520"
    ["className"]=>
    string(21) "custom-cursor bg-past"
    ["title"]=>
    string(9) "Available"
    ["status"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [14]=>
  array(6) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-03 20:30"
    ["end"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-03 21:00"
    ["id_course"]=>
    string(5) "55520"
    ["className"]=>
    string(21) "custom-cursor bg-full"
    ["title"]=>
    string(4) "Full"
    ["status"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [15]=>
  array(6) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-03 21:00"
    ["end"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-03 21:30"
    ["id_course"]=>
    string(5) "55520"
    ["className"]=>
    string(21) "custom-cursor bg-past"
    ["title"]=>
    string(9) "Available"
    ["status"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [16]=>
  array(6) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-04 08:00"
    ["end"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-04 08:30"
    ["id_course"]=>
    string(5) "55520"
    ["className"]=>
    string(21) "custom-cursor bg-full"
    ["title"]=>
    string(4) "Full"
    ["status"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [17]=>
  array(6) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-04 08:30"
    ["end"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-04 09:00"
    ["id_course"]=>
    string(5) "55520"
    ["className"]=>
    string(21) "custom-cursor bg-past"
    ["title"]=>
    string(9) "Available"
    ["status"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [18]=>
  array(6) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-04 09:00"
    ["end"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-04 09:30"
    ["id_course"]=>
    string(5) "55520"
    ["className"]=>
    string(21) "custom-cursor bg-past"
    ["title"]=>
    string(9) "Available"
    ["status"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [19]=>
  array(6) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-04 09:30"
    ["end"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-04 10:00"
    ["id_course"]=>
    string(5) "55520"
    ["className"]=>
    string(21) "custom-cursor bg-past"
    ["title"]=>
    string(9) "Available"
    ["status"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [20]=>
  array(6) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-04 10:00"
    ["end"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-04 10:30"
    ["id_course"]=>
    string(5) "55520"
    ["className"]=>
    string(21) "custom-cursor bg-full"
    ["title"]=>
    string(4) "Full"
    ["status"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [21]=>
  array(6) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-04 10:30"
    ["end"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-04 11:00"
    ["id_course"]=>
    string(5) "55520"
    ["className"]=>
    string(21) "custom-cursor bg-past"
    ["title"]=>
    string(9) "Available"
    ["status"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [22]=>
  array(6) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-04 13:00"
    ["end"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-04 13:30"
    ["id_course"]=>
    string(5) "55520"
    ["className"]=>
    string(21) "custom-cursor bg-past"
    ["title"]=>
    string(9) "Available"
    ["status"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [23]=>
  array(6) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-04 13:30"
    ["end"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-04 14:00"
    ["id_course"]=>
    string(5) "55520"
    ["className"]=>
    string(21) "custom-cursor bg-past"
    ["title"]=>
    string(9) "Available"
    ["status"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [24]=>
  array(6) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-04 14:00"
    ["end"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-04 14:30"
    ["id_course"]=>
    string(5) "55520"
    ["className"]=>
    string(21) "custom-cursor bg-past"
    ["title"]=>
    string(9) "Available"
    ["status"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [25]=>
  array(6) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-04 14:30"
    ["end"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-04 15:00"
    ["id_course"]=>
    string(5) "55520"
    ["className"]=>
    string(21) "custom-cursor bg-full"
    ["title"]=>
    string(4) "Full"
    ["status"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [26]=>
  array(6) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-04 15:00"
    ["end"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-04 15:30"
    ["id_course"]=>
    string(5) "55520"
    ["className"]=>
    string(21) "custom-cursor bg-full"
    ["title"]=>
    string(4) "Full"
    ["status"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [27]=>
  array(6) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-04 16:00"
    ["end"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-04 16:30"
    ["id_course"]=>
    string(5) "55520"
    ["className"]=>
    string(21) "custom-cursor bg-past"
    ["title"]=>
    string(9) "Available"
    ["status"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [28]=>
  array(6) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-04 16:30"
    ["end"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-04 17:00"
    ["id_course"]=>
    string(5) "55520"
    ["className"]=>
    string(21) "custom-cursor bg-past"
    ["title"]=>
    string(9) "Available"
    ["status"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [29]=>
  array(6) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-04 17:00"
    ["end"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-04 17:30"
    ["id_course"]=>
    string(5) "55520"
    ["className"]=>
    string(21) "custom-cursor bg-past"
    ["title"]=>
    string(9) "Available"
    ["status"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [30]=>
  array(6) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-04 17:30"
    ["end"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-04 18:00"
    ["id_course"]=>
    string(5) "55520"
    ["className"]=>
    string(21) "custom-cursor bg-past"
    ["title"]=>
    string(9) "Available"
    ["status"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [31]=>
  array(6) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-04 18:00"
    ["end"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-04 18:30"
    ["id_course"]=>
    string(5) "55520"
    ["className"]=>
    string(21) "custom-cursor bg-past"
    ["title"]=>
    string(9) "Available"
    ["status"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [32]=>
  array(6) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-04 18:30"
    ["end"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-04 19:00"
    ["id_course"]=>
    string(5) "55520"
    ["className"]=>
    string(21) "custom-cursor bg-past"
    ["title"]=>
    string(9) "Available"
    ["status"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [33]=>
  array(6) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-04 19:00"
    ["end"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-04 19:30"
    ["id_course"]=>
    string(5) "55520"
    ["className"]=>
    string(21) "custom-cursor bg-past"
    ["title"]=>
    string(9) "Available"
    ["status"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [34]=>
  array(6) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-04 19:30"
    ["end"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-04 20:00"
    ["id_course"]=>
    string(5) "55520"
    ["className"]=>
    string(21) "custom-cursor bg-full"
    ["title"]=>
    string(4) "Full"
    ["status"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [35]=>
  array(6) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-04 20:00"
    ["end"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-04 20:30"
    ["id_course"]=>
    string(5) "55520"
    ["className"]=>
    string(21) "custom-cursor bg-full"
    ["title"]=>
    string(4) "Full"
    ["status"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [36]=>
  array(6) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-04 20:30"
    ["end"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-04 21:00"
    ["id_course"]=>
    string(5) "55520"
    ["className"]=>
    string(21) "custom-cursor bg-full"
    ["title"]=>
    string(4) "Full"
    ["status"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [37]=>
  array(6) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-04 21:00"
    ["end"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-04 21:30"
    ["id_course"]=>
    string(5) "55520"
    ["className"]=>
    string(21) "custom-cursor bg-past"
    ["title"]=>
    string(9) "Available"
    ["status"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [38]=>
  array(7) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-05 08:00"
    ["end"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-05 08:30"
    ["id_course"]=>
    string(5) "55510"
    ["className"]=>
    string(23) "custom-cursor bg-booked"
    ["title"]=>
    string(6) "Missed"
    ["status"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["image"]=>
    string(92) "http://squline.dev/dashboard/media/images/teacher/2dd22e63084c868044b8d8840ad02e35_thumb.jpg"
  }
  [39]=>
  array(6) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-05 08:00"
    ["end"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-05 08:30"
    ["id_course"]=>
    string(5) "55510"
    ["className"]=>
    string(21) "custom-cursor bg-full"
    ["title"]=>
    string(4) "Full"
    ["status"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [40]=>
  array(6) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-05 08:30"
    ["end"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-05 09:00"
    ["id_course"]=>
    string(5) "55510"
    ["className"]=>
    string(21) "custom-cursor bg-full"
    ["title"]=>
    string(4) "Full"
    ["status"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [41]=>
  array(6) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-05 09:00"
    ["end"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-05 09:30"
    ["id_course"]=>
    string(5) "55510"
    ["className"]=>
    string(21) "custom-cursor bg-full"
    ["title"]=>
    string(4) "Full"
    ["status"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [42]=>
  array(6) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-05 09:30"
    ["end"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-05 10:00"
    ["id_course"]=>
    string(5) "55510"
    ["className"]=>
    string(21) "custom-cursor bg-full"
    ["title"]=>
    string(4) "Full"
    ["status"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [43]=>
  array(6) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-05 10:30"
    ["end"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-05 11:00"
    ["id_course"]=>
    string(5) "55510"
    ["className"]=>
    string(21) "custom-cursor bg-full"
    ["title"]=>
    string(4) "Full"
    ["status"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [44]=>
  array(6) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-05 13:00"
    ["end"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-05 13:30"
    ["id_course"]=>
    string(5) "55510"
    ["className"]=>
    string(21) "custom-cursor bg-past"
    ["title"]=>
    string(9) "Available"
    ["status"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [45]=>
  array(6) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-05 13:30"
    ["end"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-05 14:00"
    ["id_course"]=>
    string(5) "55510"
    ["className"]=>
    string(21) "custom-cursor bg-past"
    ["title"]=>
    string(9) "Available"
    ["status"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [46]=>
  array(6) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-05 14:00"
    ["end"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-05 14:30"
    ["id_course"]=>
    string(5) "55510"
    ["className"]=>
    string(21) "custom-cursor bg-past"
    ["title"]=>
    string(9) "Available"
    ["status"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [47]=>
  array(6) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-05 14:30"
    ["end"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-05 15:00"
    ["id_course"]=>
    string(5) "55510"
    ["className"]=>
    string(21) "custom-cursor bg-full"
    ["title"]=>
    string(4) "Full"
    ["status"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [48]=>
  array(6) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-05 15:00"
    ["end"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-05 15:30"
    ["id_course"]=>
    string(5) "55510"
    ["className"]=>
    string(21) "custom-cursor bg-full"
    ["title"]=>
    string(4) "Full"
    ["status"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [49]=>
  array(6) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-05 15:30"
    ["end"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-05 16:00"
    ["id_course"]=>
    string(5) "55510"
    ["className"]=>
    string(21) "custom-cursor bg-past"
    ["title"]=>
    string(9) "Available"
    ["status"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [50]=>
  array(6) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-05 16:00"
    ["end"]=>
    string(16) "2016-10-05 16:30"
    ["id_course"]=>
    string(5) "55510"
    ["className"]=>
    string(21) "custom-cursor bg-past"
    ["title"]=>
    string(9) "Available"
    ["status"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
```

My attempt to move data that I want to php array:

```
foreach( $class as $key => $val )
          { 
   if ($xcourse_date != $course_date) {
                    $events[] = $event;
                    $count_x_course_date++;
                }


                  if( $events[$count_x_course_date - 1]['status'] != 'BOOKED' ) {
                    if ( $events[$count_x_course_date - 1]['status'] != 'AVAILABLE' ) {
                        $events[$count_x_course_date - 1] = $event;
                    }
                }
                 elseif ( $events[$count_x_course_date - 1]['status'] == 'AVAILABLE' ) {
                    $events[$count_x_course_date - 1] = $event;
                } 
                $xcourse_date = $val['course_date'];
                $i++;
}
```

My question are:
1. What did I do wrong?
2. I use loop to access all the data inside the json, is there any way easier than looping?
3. My logic says I do no wrong in my code, but the result is far from my expectation, can you point out what's wrong with my programming logic?

Comment: Did you `json_decode()` the json data first?

Comment: Yes I decode the json data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your data set from database,

1. Some of the records doesn't have status field i.e. records 0-6
2. In your condition your're checking `$events[$count_x_course_date - 1]['status'] == 'AVAILABLE'` which is wrong. Because from the data set, it's saying value is boolean i.e. true/false
   `["status"] => bool(false)`.
3. Actual values which you're checking is in `title` field i.e. `["title"]=>
   string(9) "Available"`